# Autocomplete/suggest for short IDs in Trello?

Tags: trello

Trello supports referencing one card from the description and comments of another card by using the referenced card Short ID ([more info here](https://trello.com/card/short-ids-for-cards/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1003)). The only way I currently know of detecting a card Short ID is:

1. Entering into the card and looking at the "Card #" legend at the bottom of the right column.
2. Hovering with the mouse over the card and looking at the last part of the URL. It might say something like "/22", so in that case the short ID will be 22.

However, both of those methods are quite uncomfortable when you're writing the description/comment for another card.

Is there any way of having Trello autocomplete/suggest the Short ID for a card, or help with the referencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are entering info on a card, type "#" then whatever your search term for the card is and it should start matching cards for you.

For example: **#fix** should find all cards that have "fix" in their titles for you.

With this, you don't have to know the shortcode.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I had completely forgotten about this question. Things have definitely changed since 2012! Hehe, thanks again.

Comment: Just going through and answering unanswered Trello questions! Glad to help. =D